# Why nginx don't see staticfiles and Media files Django +nextjs +Docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx, next.js

I have Nginx config and using Docker to server Django, Nextjs and Nginx

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
return 403;
}
server {
listen 80;

location /staticfiles/ {
    alias /app/staticfiles/;
}
location /mediafiles/ {
    alias /app/mediafiles/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://nextjs:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location ~* ^/(api|admin) {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://server:9000;
}
```

}

The problem is when I added a location to nextjs, nginx doesn't want to see static files, but if I use config without next js django + admin it serves ok.

```
server {
listen 80;

location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy_django;
}


location @proxy_django {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://server:9000;
}

location /staticfiles/ {
    alias /app/staticfiles/;
}
location /mediafiles/ {
    alias /app/mediafiles/;
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping